# When square is inscribed how to identify the similar triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the picture, $ \square PQRS $ is a square inscribed in a right triangle. How can we come to conclusion that $ \triangle ABC \sim \triangle PBQ $?
My understanding is that $ \triangle ABC $ and $ \triangle PBQ $ have one angle in common which is the right angle. What could be the other angle which is congruent so that we can apply AA property.

I have gone through several questions and explanations but couldn't find on what basis $ \triangle ABC $ and $ \triangle PBQ $  are similar.

[image: Square inscribed in a right angle triangle]

Answer (score 1):

For this to be true, $PQRS$ doesn't even need to be a square: any parallelogram will do. Because $PQ \parallel RS$, we also have $PQ \parallel AC$, so line $AB$ makes the same angle with $PQ$ as with $AC$. This gives us another equal angle.

Comment: How can AB makes the same angle with PQ as with AC ?

Comment: Angle PQB = Angle RQC as they are vertically opposite angles. Then we conclude that Angle C = Angle P. Therefore  △ABC∼△PBQ as Angle B and Angle C are congruent. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: AB makes angle $\angle BPQ$ with $PQ$ and $\angle BAC$ with $AC$, so those angles are equal. You can also argue that $\angle PQB = \angle RCQ$ by the same reasoning. $\angle PQB$ is not equal to $\angle RQC$ in general.

Comment: Apologies ! I did not understand this line AB makes angle ∠BPQ with PQ and ∠BAC with AC ? Can you please explain me what theorem or concept you have used ?